# Update attributes on nested selections

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble updating the attributes of dom elements appended with a nested selection.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/k9zA7/1/

In brief my question is this: Given a nested data structure what is the correct way to select the nested nodes so that I can update their attributes each time the code is run, regardless of changes to the data structure?

I *think* I grok the selection and data join stuff but the behavior below is confusing to me so clearly I'm missing something. Thanks!

```
    var cities = [
        {name: 'Detroit', streets: [{name: 'E Warren Ave'}, {name: 'E Canfield St'}]},
        {name: 'San Francisco', streets: [{name: 'Capp St'}, {name: 'Mission St'}]},
        {name: 'Brooklyn', streets: [{name: '18th St'}, {name: 'Prospect Park West'}]}
    ];

    var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

    var run_count = 0;

    var draw = function() {

        var sel = d3.select('#cities').selectAll('div').data(cities);

        var streets_ul = sel.enter()
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', 'city')
            .text(function(city){return city.name})
            .append('ul')
            .attr('class', 'streets');

        // This updates the color every time it's executed, as expected
        sel.style('color', colors[run_count % 3]);

        var streets_sel = streets_ul.selectAll('streets')
                            .data(function(city){ return city.streets});

        streets_sel.enter()
            .append('li')
            .text(function(street){return street.name});

        // This only updates the color the first time it's run and is ignored on
        // subsequent executions. Why?
        streets_sel.style('color', colors[(run_count + 1) % 3]);

        run_count += 1;
    }
```

**Update**

To get this working as expected I need to create a brand new selection for appending the city name `<li>` elements instead of creating a sub-selection of my first `sel` enter selection. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9zA7/4/

```
        var streets_sel = d3.selectAll('.city ul').selectAll('li')
                    .data(function(city){ return city.streets});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few typos in your code. First, `streets_ul` (which you are using for the nested selection) contains only the enter selection of the `div`s, so it will only do something the first time you run the code. Change that to `sel`.

Second, you're selecting `streets` elements, which don't exist. This is a problem on subsequent calls as it causes the `li` elements to be appended again. Instead, select `li` elements. Finally, `colors[run_count + 1 % 3]` should be `colors[(run_count + 1) % 3]` to achieve the effect you're after.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k9zA7/2/).

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle @Lars. The problem with your code is that the <li> elements are appended as children of `<div class='city'>` instead of `<ul class='streets'>`. What is the correct way (or, is it possible) to create a new selection from a node that is created in a preceding enter selection in such a way that it retains the data join context?

Comment: Oh, I figured it out! Create a new selection like `d3.selectAll('.city ul').selectAll('li').data(function(city){ return city.streets});` 
New fiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/k9zA7/4/

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that I would loose the data context if I created a new selection that way - but I know that the data is always there. Don't know why that didn't connect for me. Thanks again.